# A question about Latent Dirichlet Allocation model

Tags: machine-learning, topic-models

when I used LDA model in my project, the result topic terms vary with the random seed. how to solve this problem ? thanks

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: I think your problem has already been discussed in that question : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63026/topic-stability-in-topic-models

Comment: I have seen the link, but the method didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is meant to vary as LDA and other topic models are stochastic methods. You can not expect exact same result in multiple runs.